# Moving ~11GB mail from PST to Outlook.com via IMAP?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, imap, microsoft-outlook-2013, outlook.com

I'm looking for any possible solutions for migrating about eleven gigs of email from an Outlook PST to Outlook.com. There are hundreds (possibly thousands) of folders and subfolders that need to be migrated, and dragging and dropping folders from the PST to the account via IMAP just doesn't work for anything but the smallest folders. Connecting via MAPI (native in Outlook 2013 for Outlook.com/Hotmail/Windows Live) doesn't let me copy folders at all.

How can I do this? It's business critical for my customer, so I really need to figure something out that won't take weeks to accomplish. Thanks!

Comment: I would contact Microsoft since you are dealing with a paid account.   There really isn't a solution to migrate offline emails into an IMAP account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Been using Mailstore Home to upload to Outlook.com:

1. download home edition ([free)](http://www.mailstore.com/en/mailstore-home-email-archiving.aspx)
2. mount your pst in outlook or thunderbird
3. open mailstore, will ask you where you want to store archive (i.e. desktop)
4. click the green archive email button and select the program you are mounting pst
5. run the archive task you just created mailstore
6. after archive task completes select the red "export email" button in mailstore
7. will need to setup outlook.com imap account using:

   - host: imap-mail.outlook.com
   - access via: imap-ssl
   - username: [enter outlook.com email]
   - password: [https://account.live.com/proofs/AppPassword?mkt=en-us]
8. run the export task and will create folder in your outlook.com folders called mailstore export

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted. It turns out that Mailstore is excellent for migrating enormous PSTs to mail services like Outlook.com and Gmail. Thanks! :)